# Randomly create a vector within specific requirements

Tags: r, random, vector, partitioning, sample

I want R to create a vector for me that has length 15, each of the 15 values being in the range 0-100 and together adding up to 100. So an example outcome could be:

```
`[12, 25, 2, 0, 6, 17, 2, 4, 1, 8, 11, 3, 5, 0, 4]`
```

or

```
`[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 92, 0, 0, 1, 0]`
```

I would like to be able to change the length, the sum and the range of values of the vector for later use. Also I want the outcome to be 'random' so that I can repeat it multiple times and getting a different vector every time.
(I have been searching for similar questions on some forums but without success unfortunately, but I feel it should not be too difficult)

I got this from someone else asking a similar question:

```
rand.vect.with.total <- function(min, max, total) {   
  x <- sample(min:max, total, replace=TRUE)       #generate random numbers  
  sum.x <- table(x)                               #count numbers   
  out = vector()   
  for (i in 1:length(min:max)) {     
  out[i] <- 
  sum.x[as.character(i)]   
  }   
  out[is.na(out)] <- 0   
  return(out) 
}
```

But then found out that it gives a vector with different length every time. I want the length of the vector to be constant and set by the function but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: The tricky part is the adding to 100 - are you happy for the values 0-15 being non-uniformly sampled?

Comment: I understand that the likelihood of a value of 92 like in the second example vector is much lower than that of a value of 10. So, these values do not have to be present uniformly in that sense. But I want the small chance of this happening to exist. So what I do not want is to steer towards some selected values myself, that should be up to the 'random process'.

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple possible implementations, and below are just two of them for examples:

- **`rmultinom` approach:**

```
> set.seed(0)

> n <- 15

> s <- 100

> (v <- rmultinom(1, s, runif(n)))
      [,1]
 [1,]   14
 [2,]    3
 [3,]    6
 [4,]   14
 [5,]    9
 [6,]    3
 [7,]   14
 [8,]    7
 [9,]    8
[10,]    4
[11,]    0
[12,]    2
[13,]    0
[14,]   11
[15,]    5
```

and check the condition fulfillment

```
> sum(v)
[1] 100

> length(v)
[1] 15
```

- **`sample` + `diff` approach:**

```
> set.seed(0)

> n <- 15

> s <- 100

> (v <- diff(c(0, sort(sample(s + n - 1, n - 1)), s + n)) - 1)
 [1]  0 12  6 12  4  3  7  7  8 13  2  1  9 16  0
```

and check the condition fulfillment

```
> sum(v)
[1] 100

> length(v)
[1] 15
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I haven't figured out a closed form analytical analysis, but simulation of the rmultinorm function 100000 times yields a max value of 34 for all 15 element vectors.  Which implies that values approximately greater than 34 and less than 100 will probably not be generated.  Does that work for you?

Comment: This is a problem named “partitioning”. I’m reasonably sure it has been asked and answered on SO before.